# How to set a form as "pristine" after submit was successful in React Final Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-final-form, final-form

As a developer I would like to disable the "Submit" button when the user successfully submitted the form using React Final Form, and enable the "Submit" button if the user enters some new text in the form.

**Current**

The variable `pristine` sets the disable prop to `true` only when the form loads for first time, but when the user submit the form (not reloading the page) the variable `pristine` is `false` and I expect it to be `true` in order to disable the "Submit" button.

**Desired behaviour**

- The Submit button is disabled when the form loads for first time.
- The Submit button is enabled when the user enters text or make changes.
- The Submit button is disabled after the user click Submit and it was successful.
- The Submit button should be enabled if the user enters more changes after submitting.

**Example of current behaviour**

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/final-form/react-final-form/tree/master/examples/simple

**My investigation**

I tried to use a combination of the following variables provided by Final Form but with unsuccessful results `pristine`, `touched`, `submitSucceeded`, `lastSubmittedValues`

Comment: do you have any code?

Comment: @ezra I provided the code, it is in here: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/final-form/react-final-form/tree/master/examples/simple

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To accomplish this, you will need to "reinitialize" the form after you submit.

After your submit is successful, you will need to pass those submitted form values back into the `initialValues` prop on `<Form/>`. That will ensure that your `pristine` value accurately reflects the values that have been saved/submitted.

If you do this, `pristine` should be the only value your submit button needs to know if it should be disabled or not.

---

Side note: Please only implement this pattern on forms that are *editing existing data*. The reason being that if you are starting with an empty form, and have required fields, attempting to submit is helpful in that it will mark all the fields as `touched` so you can display error messages. But if you disable the submit button on `pristine`, you cannot get this benefit.

Comment: Thanks for the solution; what about submitting new data and in my case, I can't disable the submit button after submitting the form in both cases after submitting the existing data and after submitting the fresh data